# What exactly is a Container in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

Could some please explain what is the exact work of Container in Spring?
I had visited some web sites and came to known that Container can be used to instantiate a bean object, manage the life cycle and can read bean config file.

Comment: Read the docs here, https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

Answer (score 0):

> The Spring container is at the core of the Spring Framework. The
>   container will create the objects, wire them together, configure them,
>   and manage their complete life cycle from creation till destruction.
>   The Spring container uses DI to manage the components that make up an
>   application. These objects are called Spring Beans, which we will
>   discuss in the next chapter.
>
> The container gets its instructions on what objects to instantiate,
>   configure, and assemble by reading the configuration metadata
>   provided. The configuration metadata can be represented either by XML,
>   Java annotations, or Java code. The following diagram represents a
>   high-level view of how Spring works. The Spring IoC container makes
>   use of Java POJO classes and configuration metadata to produce a fully
>   configured and executable system or application.

Ref : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_ioc_containers.htm

Answer (score -1):

http://javapapers.com/spring/dependency-injection-di-with-spring/  here ..read n learn from here..